# Load into Hive table imported entire data into first column only

Tags: sql, database, hadoop, hive

I am trying to copy the Hive data from one server to another server. By this, I am exporting into hive data into CSV from server1 and trying to import that CSV file into Hive in server2.

My table contains following datatypes:

bigint

string

array

Here is my commands:

**export:**

```
hive -e 'select * from sample' > /home/hadoop/sample.csv
```

**import:**

```
load data local inpath '/home/hadoop/sample.csv' into table sample;
```

After importing into Hive table, entire row data into inserted into first column only.

How can I overcome this, or else is there a better way to copy data from one server to another server?

Comment: Can you add your `create table sample` script here

Answer (score 1):

**While creating table add below line at the end of create statment**

```
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
```

**Like Below:**

```
hive>CREATE TABLE sample(id int,
                         name String) 
     ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

**Then Load Data:**

```
hive>load data local inpath '/home/hadoop/sample.csv' into table sample;
```

**For Your Example**

**sample.csv**

```
123,Raju,Hello|How Are You
154,Nishant,Hi|How Are You
```

So In above sample data first column is `bigint`, second is `String` and third is `Array` separated by `|`

```
hive> CREATE TABLE sample(id BIGINT,
                          name STRING,
                          messages ARRAY<String>) 
      ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
      COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '|';
hive> LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/hadoop/sample.csv' INTO TABLE sample;
```

**Most important point :**

> Define delimiter for collection items and don't impose the array
>   structure you do in normal programming. 
>   
> Also, try to make the field
>   delimiters different from collection items delimiters to avoid
>   confusion and unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

You really should not be using CSV as your data transfer format

- DistCp copies data between Hadoop clusters as-is
- [Hive supports Export, Import](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ImportExport)
- [Circus Train allows Hive table replication](https://github.com/HotelsDotCom/circus-train)

Answer (score 0):

why  not use hadoop command  to transfer  data from one cluster to another  such as

```
 bash$ hadoop distcp hdfs://nn1:8020/foo/bar \ 
                    hdfs://nn2:8020/bar/foo
```

then load the data to your new table

```
load data inpath '/bar/foo/*' into table wyp;
```

your problem may caused by  the  delimiter 
,The default delimiter  `'\001'` if you havn't set when create a hivetable ..
if you use `hive -e 'select * from sample' > /home/hadoop/sample.csv`  will make all  cloumn to one cloumn